# JSDoc - How to assign a function as a property of another function

Tags: jsdoc

Given the following, when I run jsdoc, the output does not show anything for the `foo.bar` property.

```
/**
 * Foo
 */
const foo = function foo() {
  //...
}

/**
 * Bar
 */
foo.bar = function bar() {
  //...
}
```

How can I display `bar` as being a property on `foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities to achieve this. The following are just a couple of them ...

- Use [@memberof](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html) which is the tag identifies a member symbol that belongs to a parent symbol.

  ```
  /**
   * Foo
   */
  const foo = function foo() {
     //...
  }

  /**
   * Bar
   * @memberof Foo
   */
  foo.bar = function bar() {
     //...
  }
  ```
- Use [@prop](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-property.html) which is the tag to easily document a list of static properties of a class, namespace or other object.

  ```
  /**
   * Foo
   * @namespace
   * @property {object}  bar - is this "bar" property?
   */
  const foo = function foo() {
     //...
  }

  /**
   * Bar
   */
  foo.bar = function bar() {
     //...
  }
  ```

You may use [@alias](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-alias.html) as well, it's all depend on what is your Foo and Bar; Are they objects, namespace, functions, properties, etc. I would suggest to read a bit on [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) documentation to get to know all the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. I went through the docs, but couldn't get a solution. Turned out I complicated the issue by using the @module tag.

Answer (score 1):

here is a `@typedef` solution, with property comments

```js
// types.js
/**
* @typedef {(s: string) => number} _SomeFunction
* convert string to number
*
* @typedef {Object} SomeProps
* @property {number} someProp1 some property 1
* @property {string} someProp2 some property 2
* @property {(s: string) => number} someProp3
* some property 3
*
* @typedef {_SomeFunction & SomeProps} SomeFunction
*/
```

```js
/** @typedef {import("./types.js").SomeFunction} SomeFunction */

/** @type {SomeFunction} */
var f = s => s.length
f.someProp1 = 1
f.someProp2 = ""
f.someProp3 = s => (2 * s.length)
```